# Оставшиеся параметры (...rest) в TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Есть функция createRequest, которая принимает в себя функцию `func`, и возвращает асинхронную функцию `action`, которая внутри себя будет вызывать функцию `func`. Как сделать так, что бы функция `action` принимала в себя только параметры `func`, будто вызывается непосредственно функция `func`?

```
function createRequest(func: Function): Function {
      // входящие параметры функции action должны соответствовать 
      // входящим параметрам функции func
      return async function action(...args: any) {
        // other code...
        func(...args);
        // ...other code
      }
    }
```

Например:

```
function A (a: number, b: string) {
  return [a, b];
}

const B = createRequest(A);

B(1, 'a'); // корректный вызов, передающиеся параметры правильного типа
B(1, 2); // некорректный вызов, typescript должен выдавать ошибку типов
```

На данный момент код работает, но нужно проверка типов TypeScript.

Наткнулся на `Parameters<Type>`, однако мне не совсем понятно, как это применить, и подходит ли это вообще.

Comment: что за `F` используется тут `func: F`?

Comment: Извиняюсь, ошибка, поправил, там тип Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для использования [`Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype), нужно чтобы `T` был совместим с сигнатурой `(...args: any): any`.

Поэтому в данном случае не получится использовать тип `Function`.

Однако можно сделать функцию `createRequest` шаблонной

```
createRequest<T>
```

и добавить, что `T` расширяет `(...args: any): any`

```
createRequest<T extends (...args:any)=>any>(func: T)
```

Так же можно добавить тип возвращаемого значения

```
function createRequest<T extends (...args:any)=>any>(func: T): (...args:Parameters<T>)=>Promise<void> {
```

Теперь, для возвращаемой функции достаточно просто указать тип параметров:

```
return async function action(...args: Parameters<T>) {
```

теперь, чтобы заработал

```
func(...args);
```

Нужно указать, что тип у `args` - массив, для этого нужно изменить либо в обертке

```
createRequest<T extends (...args:any[])=>any>(func: T)
```

либо в возвращаемой функции

```
    return async function action(...args: Parameters<T>[]) {
```

Итоговый код может выглядеть так:

```
function createRequest<T extends (...args:any[])=>any>(func: T): (...args:Parameters<T>)=>Promise<void> {
      // входящие параметры функции action должны соответствовать 
      // входящим параметрам функции func
      return async function action(...args: Parameters<T>) {
        // other code...
        func(...args);
        // ...other code
      }
    }

function A (a: number, b: string) {
  return [a, b];
}

const B = createRequest(A);

B(1, 'a'); // корректный вызов, передающиеся параметры правильного типа
B(1, 2); // некорректный вызов, typescript должен выдавать ошибку типов
```

[Пример для запуска](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQJTQRxDQGcoAeAFUTQA9swATYxACgDoOMUBzYgLgxgAngG0AugEoAvAD5BQmS1CQ%20iChNXtOPfgAUuGALZpsKYpRnSZulHEMxiaMgDc4MBjMQBvAFCJ-AQD0gYiATCCAoiCAfCCALCCA8iCAkiCAHCCArCCIgPwggAwggAIgGYA8IMmAQiBZgNIgiIAiIIDCIIC8IIBcIIBiIImJiBjQ8EjRkYDcIIBsIFWlgIIgkZEFoYX9I5GhGQWAMiCIfgH%20wWFRcUm56dl5hTkblbUNTcoQC4voUCAoSBjEQpCIx7AIza0IWmxcvKr6KEYmaGYLBJvKdFohlnAoAALAHIOAMNAcNigxbHd6fYgSADcKKCISRkJhKDhCNxAF9QRSfI82ogAIKsDCqMAgQwAIwBABpEGzVKQUDAwNxgb5-OdLkgRBhuWyxDiqRAEKREAAhRBSZDoLC4AhEUgsOnYnw%20FUsACM3IA5BhLdjwSEapEsllkjUCn1AJwgYWKgHYQSbctLJF3RDKAORAksl%20rFNrsdqU0jlQolOjMqpFAMwgkUQBUSmRN5u5ACY7csqq6nS63Z7vX7QtyoEIAA4kVAwRtQRAdHrJKrekNTWaISKACRBEoBGEBqFWzucmQA)

Comment: как насчёт добавить к вопросу тэг  [tag:typescript-типы]?

Comment: Перемудрил, можно проще.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вообще то же самое получилось, просто ты тип параметра, а я самой функции в generic вынес

Comment: Ну так в этом и заключается "проще" ;) Впрочем, допускаю, что в некоторых случаях последствия будут разными - тайпскрипт - такой тайпскрипт...

Comment: Кстати, не хочешь заглянуть на enSO в мои вопросы по тайпскрипту, особенно в [неотвеченные](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a4928642%20is%3aq%20%5btypescript%5d%20hasaccepted%3ano&mixed=0)?

Answer (score 0):

[Песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQJTQRxDQGcoAeAQRQHNjE0APbMAEzozAE8BtAXQD4AFKEgAuRIIB00jDWLiqtAJSIAvP0QA3ODBYqA3gFgAUIjOJ0UECiQZinSIhHR4tlwiky5CuQZPmAp3AIT0lZZQBuf3MAXxM44xNnWAQnQQxxMBAAWwAjNBQAGkRc8VIUGDBqP1MLNCsbRG4MYtzeKOMEkwgEUkRqNWR0LFwCIlJhJQ6TakEARmKAcgxFqcQAenXEOABrGfnigCY1s03ERRy0MCht4EQoTgAHNERFrLyCxcQYOjA4G7sxBg1DAGFyABsXlA4IhHrIMNl6gVbvcni9FuVKtRFpIgA)

```
function createRequest<Args extends any[]>(func: (...args: Args) => void) {
    return async function action(...args: Args) {
        func(...args);
    }
}

function f(a: number, b: string) {
  return [a, b];
}

const g = createRequest(f);

g(1, 'a'); // ok
g(1, 2);   // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```